# Photoshop produce a specific effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, effects

How can I recreate this Photoshop effect:

[image: desired effect]

Let's say that I have a heart image and inside of the heart I want to implement this effect.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sparkle or [glitter brush](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/photoshop-brushes-light-sparkles/) to cover a heart image.
Check out also those [heart](http://www.youthedesigner.com/2010/02/07/30-free-adobe-photoshop-valentine-brush-sets/) brushes.
Also you should check out this tutorial:

[www.denisdesigns.com/blog/2010/02/create-a-jumbotron-effect-in-photoshop](http://www.denisdesigns.com/blog/2010/02/create-a-jumbotron-effect-in-photoshop)

It will help you to create a pattern and repeat it on the heart image. 
And last check this halftone tutorial:

[psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/photoshop-halftone-effect](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/photoshop-halftone-effect)

If you go with jumbotron effect or halftone effect then light up some areas and you will have a result like the one shown in the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but this is what i have already tried to do and it wasn't so efficient. I want a clear guide how to do it from the beginning or if you have any brush which can do that effect directly! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pattern: Make a single "field" (a.k.a. one diamond), then save it as pattern `[Edit] > [Set Pattern]`. Then add it as pattern layer and set a light grey layer below it. For further details search for a pattern tutorial in a search engine. For the boundries you could use a vector mask.

Comment: Also. to achieve the level of random lighting that the actual diamonds have, instead of one diamond, you could do four, or six, and make some of them seem to shine brighter.

Comment: Or maybe use a b/w cloud filter on the layer below. This should give the right random effect.